# Too fast swipe in Unity game

Tags: unity, transformation

I am letting the user to swipe around in some movement and to see the scene on mobile device.
Facing too fast swipe.
Need to make swipe slower, smother.Using the code:

```
foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(
        transform.localEulerAngles.x + touch.deltaPosition.y, transform.localEulerAngles.y + touch.deltaPosition.x, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
}
```

Comment: Multiplying deltaPosition on a scalar won't work?

Comment: @Ocelot can you please show me an example?

Comment: `transform.localEulerAngles.x + touch.deltaPosition.y * scalar` where scalar is whatever you want it to be - 0.5 will make it twice slower, 2.0 will make it twice faster.

Comment: you can add an answer and I will mark it. It helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the movement speed by multiplying `touch.deltaPosition` values on a scalar.

`transform.localEulerAngles.x + touch.deltaPosition.y * scalar`

Where `scalar` is whatever you want it to be - 0.5 will make it twice slower, 2.0 will make it twice faster.